# How to set Browser when using Response.Write

Tags: asp.net, xml, httpresponse, response.addheader

My application is  writing XML to a file 
which is then downloaded (Response.Write) and the user can then open.

Question:
No matter what Browser I'm using (Chrome, Firefox,etc.) the downloaded file is 
opened in IE.
I want the downloaded file to be opened in the browser which created it.

```
        strXML = "<ROWSET></ROWSET>";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"kupot.xml\"");
        Response.Write(strXML);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        Response.Close();
```

What should I do so that if the downloaded file was created in, for example, Chrome, then when it's downloaded and I'm asked if I want to open it, then if I answer YES then it'll be opened in Chrome

All help/ideas is appreciated.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

Drop the content disposition header. This tells the browser you want to download it as a raw file. This of course will be opened by whatever is associated with the XML file type on your system.

If you just want to return XML content directly to the browser use:

```
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Response.Write(strXML);
    Response.Flush();
```

You also probably don't need to do `Clear`, `Charset`, `End` and `Close`.